# Compute probability of event involving two independently distributed random variables, one normal, one uniform

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am looking to compute the probability of an event involving two independent random variables, X and Y, where $X∼N(2700,300)$ and $Y∼U(0,400)$ I am looking for $Pr(3000+Y<X)$. I have searched similar questions, but they usually refered to very complex functional forms that go beyond my level in statistics. It would be great if you could show me how to compute this probability.

Comment: Let $Z=X-3000\sim\mathcal N(-300,300)$. Then you want to compute $P(Y<Z)$. By the law of iterated expectations and independence, $P(Y<Z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y<z)f(z)dz$, where $f$ is the pdf of $Z$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful to get me started.

Comment: Great! Note also that $P(Y<z)=0$ if $z<0$, $P(Y<z)=z/400$ if $0\leq z\leq 400$ and $P(Y<z)=1$ if $z>400$. This should make the computations rather easy, I hope!

Comment: I see that I can decompose the interval into $\int_{-\inf}^0$, $\int_{0}^{400}$ and  $\int_{400}^{\inf}$, where $Pr(Y<z)\phi(z)$ is zero in the first interval, $\frac{z}{400}\phi(z)dz$ in the second interval and $1-\Phi(400)$ in the third interval. I computed those two probabilities separately in Matlab, resulting in a probability of 0.0502 + 0.0098 = 0.06.